# Waiting for a callback in a Callable

Tags: java, future, callable

I want to do something like this:

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<Boolean>, MyObserver
{
    Boolean mSuccess = false;

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception
    {
        // ... Wait here until myCallback is called ...

        return mSuccess;
    }

    @Override
    public void myCallback()
    {
        if(something) mSuccess = true;
    }
}
```

so I can use it like:

```
MyCallable callable = new MyCallable();

FutureTask<Boolean> futureTask = new FutureTask<Boolean>(callable);

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
executor.execute(futureTask);

Boolean successfull = futureTask.get();
```

What would this "Wait for the callback to be called" code look like? I guess I could just make a member called "Boolean mCallbackCalled = false" and just while(!mCallbackCalled), but that seems pretty hacky...

Comment: Consider using a `CountDownLatch`, but this doesn't seem like the appropriate design.

Comment: Perhaps a `BlockingQueue`? Also doesn't seem appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using executors at all.

Instead, create a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) with a count of 1, `countDown()` it in the callback, then `await()` it in your calling code.

Comment: @SLacks I don't suppose there is an easy way to set a timeout on a CountDownLatch? That is, "wait for the count to happen, but if it doesn't in 5 seconds, proceed anyway"?

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick on the trigger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245629/abort-countdownlatch-await-after-time-out . Thanks for the pointer!