# How to explicitly release CountDownLatch

Tags: java, multithreading, countdownlatch

Is there any way to explicitly release `CountDownLatch` - means without do `countDown()`.

E.g.: Let say I am waiting for 100 threads to do `countDown()`, but if something fails, I would like to release this latch without anymore waiting. I was thinking to `getCount()` on latch & then in for cycle do `countDown()`, but its not optimal way.

Any suggestions / ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

The [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) has an overloaded [await()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method which takes *time* and *time unit* as inputs and releases the lock once the given time elapses

Comment: "but if something fails" - wouldn't interrupting be more appropriate here?

Comment: I am pointing to that release() method would be very useful, like in Semaphore

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Semaphore`, which is close to a `CountDownLatch` and it's impl has methods for manipulating it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use await with timeout?

```
boolean await(long timeout, TimeUnit unit);
```

If the specified waiting time elapses then the value false is returned, otherwise true is returned on await completion.

[Abort countDownLatch.await() after time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245629/abort-countdownlatch-await-after-time-out)

If you want to stop execution of other threads, if any thread fails - you'll need some additional communication layer.

For example:

```
AtomicBoolean kill = new AtomicBoolean(false);
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(SOME_NUM);

class Task extends Runnable {
     public void run() {
         try {
              ....
              if (kill.get())
                  throw new Exception();
              ....
         } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            kill.set(true);
         } finally {
            countDownLatch.countDown();
         }
     }
}
```

If you just want to release count down on Throwable, regardless of other processes, you can do countDown in loop on Exception

```
class Task extends Runnable {
     public void run() {
         try {
              ....
         } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            while(countDownLatch.getCount() != 0)
               countDownLatch.countDown();
         } finally {
            countDownLatch.countDown();
         }
     }
}
```

You can combine 2 countDown tasks

```
CountDownLatch A = new CountDownLatch(1);
CountDownLatch B = new CountDownLatch(1);

class CountDownTracker extend Runnable {
     public void run() {
         B.await();
         A.countDown();
     }
}

class Task extends Runnable {
     public void run() {
         try {
              ....
         } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            A.countDown();
         } finally {
            B.countDown();
         }
     }
}
```

in this case A will finish after completion, or any Task failure.

And so on...

Comment: but in case I dont the time know what all operations consume, its useless.

Comment: You specify max timeout for operations, and go from there. You'll need to have some kind of completion timeout anyway, regardless of desired implementation.

Comment: I dont need timeout, I need to explicitly release()

Comment: If you look at the question, I wanted to avoid countDown in loop.

Comment: There is last option, with combined CountDownLatches. Using while countdown loop costs nothing, so it's not a problem doing while release.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers:

it depends on what "but if something fails" means, but if failing means you catch an Exception in a worker thread, you may count down the latch within the catch clause as well. This of course changes the meaning of countDown from "Successfully processed" to "processing complete" - so your code has to handle this..

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your use case allows solving the problem with keyboard interactive input. Instead of CoundDownLatch or Semaphore you could then expect manual input in System.in:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.nextLine();
```

If you need that in unit tests, make sure that your environment is set up to read the user input, e.g. start the IntelliJ Idea with `-Deditable.java.test.console=true` option in Help -> "Edit Custom VM Options..."